# How to convert and transpose merged dataframes to get total population by income group in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, aggregate, transpose

Python with default argument get_total_pop_by_income(income_group_name='Low income') that converts merged dataframe and gives a transposed array

def get_total_pop_by_income(income_group_name='Low income'):

```
#Merged Dataframes

joined_df = meta_df.merge(population_df, how='inner', on='Country Code')
join = joined_df.drop(columns =['Region', 'Special Notes'])

# Create Income group name list
checker = set(meta_df['Income Group'].values.tolist())    

if income_group_name in checker:   
    joint = join.groupby(['Income Group']).sum().T.reset_index().to_numpy(dtype=int)
else:   
    ValueError()
return joint
```

[image: Expected]

Should take a str argument, called income_group_name as input and return a numpy array type as output.
Set the default argument of income_group_name to equal 'Low income'.
If the specified value of income_group_name does not exist, the function must raise a ValueError.
The array should only have two columns containing the year and the population, in other words, it should have a shape (?, 2) where ? is the length of the data.
The values within the array should be of type np.int64.[image: DataExpected]